# Meaning of symbol: $\Sigma\!\!\!\!\!\int$ (superimposion of integral sign with capital sigma) in QFT

Tags: notation, quantum-field-theory

In some note I see the integral sign: $\int$ with sigma $\Sigma$ over it. I've never seen this before. When I had analysis I never had it neither.

What is it suppose to mean $\Sigma\!\!\!\!\!\int$ subject is quantum field theory?

Comment: In what context did it appear specifically?  What class, what theorems, what type of problem, etc...  Also, do you mean a symbol something like this: $\Sigma\!\!\!\!\!\int$?

Comment: This denotes "the sum over all discrete states and the integral over continuous states".

Comment: The usual context is a "mixed" distribution...say a random variable $X$ which is $1$ with probability $\frac 12$ and is otherwise chosen uniformly from $[0,\frac 12]$.

Comment: @JMoravitz In quantum field theory. yes that is the symbol.

Comment: @Lulu I've seen it in quantum field theory, so that is what it means?thank you!